# Transfer Files Between 2 Server

Tags: ftp, scp, transfer

Is there any recommendation to transfer files between 2 ubuntu server faster? I've already tried scp and ftp, and it take a day to transfer about 15 GB files

Comment: I guess that'll be more of a network problem in your case? But anyway, it also sounds like you should consider `rsync`. It won't solve your network problems, though. Or are the disks busy all the time and your servers never stop swapping?

Comment: i hope this is not my network problem. Is it really different when i use scp and ftp?? because i have different speed of transfer using those protocol. anyway, how to setup `rsync` as you suggest? @ClassStacker

Comment: How do you copy the files, by the way? Directly from server 1 to server 2? Or via your own machine? Because the data rate is... suspicious. If these servers actually do something important, you should find the root cause. `rsync` won't help much because what you see is orders of magnitude away from what one would expect.

Comment: Please add a lot more information to the question. Things like the actual command line you're using to do the transfer, how these two machines are connected, etc, are essential to allow proper debugging of this issue.

Comment: Are you downloading the files from one server to your local machine, then uploading the files from your local machine to the other server?  If so, then you might look into using server-to-server FTP transfers (commonly called "FXP"), where the two FTP servers talk directly, and the files are **not** downloaded to your machine.  Clients like [SmartFTP](https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/14) can do this, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If they're close to each other, there's always good old sneakernet. 15
GB on a USB 3.0 drive would not take more than maybe 10 minutes on each
end. Maybe 30 minutes without USB 3.0.

Comment: yes, they're close to each other, but far from me, so i need to remote them